# Generic many-to-many relationships in django admin

Tags: django, generics, django-admin, many-to-many

I have few similar models in Django:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class News(Material):
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=NEWS_STATE_CHOICES)

class Article(Material):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, verbose_name='genre')
```

And model **Topic**, which is related to News and Article as ManyToMany.

I'd like to use Generic many-to-many relationships like in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933092/generic-many-to-many-relationships). But question is how to use default ManyToMany widget in django admin. Or another convenient analogue.

**UPD**: If I didn't use generics I'd write

```
class News(Material): 
    topic = models.ManyToMany(Topic) 

class Article(Material):
    topic = models.ManyToMany(Topic)
```

And I'd get 2 identical tables that express these relationships. I wonder if I could use generics in order to have one intermediate table, because not only news and articles may have topic in my database. News and articles may be connected with 2 or more topics as well.

Comment: Not sure how the question you linked to is related. Do you want to switch from having ManyToMany relationships with Topic to giving Topic a GenericForeignKey so you can "attach" it to any object? In which direction do you want to have a multiselect list widget? News to select its topic? If it's a generic relationship the select list of Topic would have to show everything..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Check this out http://charlesleifer.com/blog/connecting-anything-to-anything-with-django/

GenericForeignKey's are unfortunately not as well supported as ForeignKey's. There's an open (and accepted) ticket with patch for providing a widget for them: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9976

What is provided out-of-the-box is managing objects with GenericForeignKey inline.

Assuming your generic relationship is achieved by

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...
```

and

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    ...
    news = generic.GenericRelation('News')   # if separate app: 'newsapp.News'
```

If you want to edit the News of a Topic, you can define an inline admin for News:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericTabularInline

class NewsInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = News
```

and add it to the inlines of Topic admin:

```
class TopicAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (NewsInline, )
```

That said, from the information given I can't see what's wrong with your ManyToMany relationship. It seems to express what you need.

Maybe you're defining the ManyToMany field in Topic instead of in News and Article? Define them in News and Article.

EDIT: Thanks for the clarification. Your model setup would be as per arie's post (i.e., the other way around) and you'd be editing inline. If you just want to select existing Topic's from inside a News/Article/etc. instance, I'm not aware of anything out-of-the-box for GenericRelation (which usually just serves as a reverse-lookup helper). You could

a) Override the admin form and add a ModelMultipleChoiceField with the queryset as per the GenericRelation

b) Override save() to adjust the relations.

Quite a lot of work. I would personally stick with multiple m2m tables and not cram everything into one. If you are afraid of the database doing multiple lookups when you ask for all News and Articles and etc. of one or more Topic's, then be aware that a generic solution will always have a similar setup to the requirements GenericForeignKey has, i.e. additional columns for model and id. That could lead to a lot more queries (e.g. against content_type for each result).

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Nevertheless, in your variant I open topic entry and choose (or add/delete) new peace of news and articles. It's not what I want. I've updated question.

Comment: Thanks, but I've hardly noticed your editing. I've seen django-generic-m2m app on github but I don't understand how to apply it to django admin.

Comment: I'm trying to use your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28437208/1075247) but I'm getting stuck. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it work if you just turn Danny's example around and define the generic relation on the side of of the `Topic`-Model?

See the example in django's docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline

Adapted to this question:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
```

It probably makes sense to additionally define the [reverse relationsship](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) on each related model.

```
class News(models.Model):
    topics = generic.GenericRelation(Topic)
```

And now you could create a `TopicInline` and attach Topics to news, articles, whatever ...

```
class TopicInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = Topic

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TopicInline,
    ]

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TopicInline,
    ]
```

Comment: But if topic has already been created, can I choose it using TabularInline?