# Autopopulate a set of generic many to many fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I'm trying to combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116452/1075247) answer and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700749/1075247), with a bit of for looping.

On creating a character, I want to add all possible skills with a value of 0 but I'm getting confused on how to follow the above answers.

I have this mixin:

```
class CrossCharacterMixin(models.Model):
    cross_character_types = models.Q(app_label='mage', model='mage')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=cross_character_types,
                                     null=True, blank=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

<sub>(eventually, the `cross_character_types` will be expanded)</sub>

And this model:

```
class CharacterSkillLink(Trait, CrossCharacterMixin):
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Primary'), (2, 'Secondary'), (3, 'Tertiary')
    )
    skill = models.ForeignKey('SkillAbility')
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default=None)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        spec_string = " (" + self.speciality + ")" if self.speciality else ""
        return self.skill.skill.label + spec_string
```

What I've started writing is this, on the NWODCharacter model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        character_skills_through = CharacterSkillLink.content_object.model

        CharacterSkillLink.objects.bulk_create([
            [character_skills_through(skill=SkillAbility(
                skill), content_object=self) for skill in SkillAbility.Skills]
        ])

    super(NWODCharacter, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This doesn't work as I don't think I'm passing in the right objects.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116452/1075247) though:

> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Users(models.Model):
>     pass
>
> class Sample(models.Model):
>     users = models.ManyToManyField(Users)
>
> Users().save()
> Users().save()
>
> # Access the through model directly
> ThroughModel = Sample.users.through
>
> users = Users.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2])
>
> sample_object = Sample()
> sample_object.save()
>
> ThroughModel.objects.bulk_create([
>     ThroughModel(users_id=users[0].pk, sample_id=sample_object.pk),
>     ThroughModel(users_id=users[1].pk, sample_id=sample_object.pk)
> ])
> ```

In this situation, what is my `ThroughModel`? Is it `CharacterSkillLink.content_object.model` ?

How do I do this in my scenario? I'm sorry if this is trivial, but I'm struggling to get my head round it.

Comment: Could the downvoter let me know how to improve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `CharacterSkillLink` itself is your through model in this case... it generically joins a content type to a `SkillAbility`

If you think about it, it also makes sense that if you're doing a `bulk_create` the objects that you pass in must be of the same model you're doing a `bulk_create` on.

So I think you want something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    initialise_skill_links = not self.pk
    super(NWODCharacter, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if initialise_skill_links:
        CharacterSkillLink.objects.bulk_create([
            CharacterSkillLink(
                skill=SkillAbility.objects.get_or_create(skill=skill)[0],
                content_object=self
            )
            for skill in SkillAbility.Skills
        ])
```

Note you had too many pairs of `[]` inside your `bulk_create`.

Also I think you should use `SkillAbility.objects.get_or_create()`... for a foreign key you need the related object to exist. Just doing `SkillAbility()` won't fetch it from the db if it already exists and won't save it to the db if it doesn't.

Comment: Literally just left work,  and heading home. Will try to use this tomorrow.  You're right btw,  `CharacterSkillLink` is my through model...I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: This works fine on my admin page, but it wasn't displaying any skills in the drop down box (separate issue) for that inline. I removed the inlines to see if it'd create and save  the skills regardless, but now it's giving me two errors. The first is at the top of the error page: `ValueError at /admin/characters/mage/add/` and 
`Cannot assign "(<SkillAbility: Academics>, False)": "CharacterSkillLink.skill" must be a "SkillAbility" instance.` and then, `Error in formatting: 'CharacterSkillLink' object has no attribute 'speciality'` setting `speciality = ""` and specifying has no effect. Help?

Comment: I found the issue `get_or_create` returns a tuple, and skill is assigned this tutple, not a `SkillAbility` object. This seems like it should work (it doesn't error) but I don't think it is working. I've added a GenericRelation to it and when I save, and try to access `mage_instance.skills.all()` it returns and empty list.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the edit you wanted to make, also added `[0]` to deal with the tuple issue

Comment: I'm just testing this works now...I don't think it does but when I'm looking at the db in a db viewer the tables for CharacterSkillLink aren't being updated properly, the object_id is blank. Not sure if that is expected/normal?

Comment: yes the problem is there is no `object_id` able to be set yet, because we are executing this code in a `if not self.pk` block... will update the answer

Comment: Well...yeah that seems obvious now you say it.

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but what if I have a subclass that also calls save? Will that conflict? I'm begining to see how this is working now. If need be we could continue in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70715/room-for-pureferret-and-anentropic)

Comment: when you call `super` in the overridden `save` method of the subclass it will run the code above, so the mechanism will work fine still, you just have to decide in the subclass which things you want to do before the super call and which things after

Comment: I have a similar 'initialise' specific to the subclass. I'm trying to figure out whether or not it would conflict. Thanks for all your efforts though :)