# Retrieving objects from many-to-many with abstract class in Django

Tags: django, django-models

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933092/generic-many-to-many-relationships), but creating junction table is not good in this particular case.

Short snippet of a model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', blank=True, null=True, related_name='photo_in_%(class)ss')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then I have **many** classes like this:

```
class Article(Item): pass
class BlogEntry(Item): pass
class Country(Item): pass
...
```

And of course:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    pass
```

Having e.g. `a = Article()` I can easily get photos in article with `a.photos.all()`

The question is: having `p = Photo()` how to retrieve all objects with this photo?

**But:**

Generic relation is not an option. Each photo can be in various items' photos simultaneously.

I came up with such a method, though. But it uses eval and *eval is evil*...

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    def get_items_with_photo(self):
        items = []
        for cl in [name for name in dir(self) if name.startswith('photo_in')]:
            qset = eval('self.%s.all()' % (cl))
            [items.append(item) for item in qset]
        return items
```

I would appreciate any different (better) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
qset = eval('self.%s.all()' % (cl))
```

do:

```
photo_attr = getattr(self, cl)
qset = photo_attr.all()
```

Comment: Thanks - works great! I assume that there is no Django-like approach  to do such a thing?

Comment: Why have a Django-like approach when the Python approach already work? No need to reinvent the wheel. If it work great, you should accept the answer!

Comment: Just because not every Python approach works well while modelling and dealing with Django's ORM. I know I should accept your answer - but what's the hurry ;)?